# Hiding Domain Name when Redirecting Other Domains

Tags: domains, redirects

I have a website whose name is specific to the product sold there. I am branching out to related products and have purchased domain names that reflect the new products. I would like to direct the new domains to a landing page in the original domain, but I would like to mask the name of the original domain. Is this possible? I can do the redirects by managing the DNS on my host, so that's not the problem.

For example, my original domain name is something like thingsforbabies.com. I am trying to reach an older child market so I purchased domain names like thingsforboys.com, thingsforgirls.com, thingsforteens.com.

When someone enters one of the new domain names, I would like to take them to the landing page that features these products, but I don't want thingsforbabies.com to be part of the address.

Any ideas on how to do this without a lot of coding, which I am not very good at. Thank you for your help

Comment: It's possible via domain alias rather than a redirect. No idea what hosting you are using, however the following article explains the difference between an alias and a redirect
https://www.buycpanel.com/difference-domain-alias-domain-redirect/

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it.  The host is GoDaddy, BTW